# php: How to store individual values from an array in separate variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I run a php script which returns coordinates in an array. However, I am struggling to store the individual values for longitude and latitude.

The actual output using var_dump is:

array(2) { ["latitude"]=> float(53.545858) ["longitude"]=> float(10.0079285) }

Any help is highly appreciated since I am a beginner with regards to php.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code on what you are doing.

Comment: But why?  Just use the array as intended.

Comment: you can you extract() function  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store them in variables $longitude and $latitude,
This should work.

```
    $longitude = $array["longitude"];
    $latitude = $array["latitude"];
```